# Foundation- Contact Form adjustment

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contacts

I have been using the foundation template to create my website. Since the layout of the form is in rows and columns I am trying to change the width of the textfields as they are way too big across the page. When I do specify a height for them the form moves to the left of the page and is not centered. I want to keep it centered as well as having the textfields a little smaller. The website is http://www.f-sharpmedia.com/

```
HTML:


<!-- Contact Form -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="panel">


  <!-- This is where the main form is created for the contact page-->

    <div id="form">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">

  <div class="panel">
  <h1>Contact F-Sharp Media</h1>
  <br>
<p>Got a creative project for us? Please share as much detail as you can to help us
ensure we can connect you with<br> the right people here at F-Sharp Media. <p>
<div class="large-3 columns">    
</div>

</div>
</div>  
 <!-- FORM -->
 <div id="form">
 <form action="sendmail.php" method="post">

 <p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="required">
  <span>Please enter your name</span>
  </p>

<p>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="required"> 
<span>Please enter a valid email address</span>
</p>

<p>
<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input name="subject" id="subject" type="text"> 
<span>Please enter your subject</span>
</p>

<p>
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea> 
<span>Please enter your message</span>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-submit">
</p>
</form>
</div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="large-9  columns ">

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Given website link is broken.

Comment: Check it again I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Add the following class in your CSS.

```
 .grid_12.omega form p
{
  width:75%; /* Increase or decrease this width to adjust your textbox */
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: That has not changed anything @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: it was a small mistake in my answer. now you copy and check it out.